# my Rainfall Dataset has no Seasonality and is stationary?

Tags: time-series, data-science, statsmodels, arima, statistical-test

I have a dataset (timeseries from 2010 to 2019 rainfall data from various districts near vellore).

When I ran the ADF(Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test) i got my dataset to be Stationary! meaning no seasonality!

My question is that am I doing something wrong? because normally rainfall occurs more in particular months(rainy season ofc) So shouldn't there be seasonality in my dataset?

**ADF Result**

Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:

Test Statistic                -1.770941e+01

p-value                        3.507811e-30

#Lags Used                     7.000000e+00

Number of Observations Used    3.644000e+03

Critical Value (1%)           -3.432146e+00

Critical Value (5%)           -2.862333e+00

Critical Value (10%)          -2.567192e+00

According to this result my test statistic of -17.7 is very small compared to critical values -2.56(10%) Hence this means my data is already stationary!.

Dataset contains daily data so there are a lot of 0's too, does this affect the seasonality?

Thank you!

Comment: How did you set the lag? Does it correspond to the expected seasonality of your data?

Comment: rainfall from one day to the next will not have a unit root. Testing for unit root with daily lags will not detect annual seasonal trends. Seasonal pattern will also be stable over time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the same with KPPS test with checking the seasonal Trend
kpps(df,regression='ct')

The parameter regression = 'ct' will check over the seasonal trend

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).